# llamada ajax no funciona

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, api

Estoy iniciando en este mundo de Javascript con JQUERY y estoy haciendo un proyecto estoy utilizando paginas aspx para renderizar JSON a traves de Webmethod con Newtonsoft.JSON y en el frontend estoy utilziando paginas HTML. En un archivo JS coloco todo mi codigo Javascript-JQUERY y utilizo funciones para ejecutar la lógica del lado cliente.

El problema es que tengo un Webmethod que despliega un JSON

[image: Webmethod despliega datos serializados en JSON]

Hasta aquí todo bien, eso creo.

El problema es que estoy llamando el JSON desde Ajax vía la pulsación del evento click del botón, mi función se encuentra dentro del archivo de librería .JS y cuando debugueo via Chrome entra correctamente a la función y ejecuta varios pasos previos correctamente pero cuando entra a la linea $.ajax({}) simplemente salta hacia el final y no procesa el llamado de la Servicio Web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función siguiente obtiene el valor del input usuario y lo valida previamente vía otra función, dependiendo del resultado pasa a la llamada ajax para pasar el parámetro vía la propiedad data: JSON.stringify({ _cedula: _ced}). _cedula es el parámetro que tiene la función del Webmethod para hacer el filtro y retornar el resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En conclusión, no entra de la llamada ajax cuando hago el DEBUG en chrome y por ende no va a procesar la lógica para continuar si no hace esta parte, como novato en Javascript no se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien me pudiera orientar. Gracias de antemano.

P.D. he visto videos y tutoriales y no doy con el problema..

Comment: Estimado, gracias por responde... La función validaCedula es un mecanismo de validar el # de cedula de mi pais, DNI en otros países. Utilizo este como usuario de autenticación por normas y políticas donde laboro. Esta función su propósito es determinar si el numero es real y no continua ejecutando cuando devuelve true.

Comment: Ok... haz hecho la prueba de comentar esa condición y ver si realmente funciona `$ajax()`? Ya que dices que no entra en ella... y mira en la consola `Network -> XHR` si te arroja algún error...

Comment: no entiendo, como puede ser que pongas en el browser la url al aspx y veas un json de respuesta si se supone que esta en un webmethod de nombre `loginProcess` y que ademas es `POST`, cuando pones una url esta se invoca con `GET`, ahi hay algo raro. Para invocar el webmethod deberias usar alguna tool como ser Postman que permite realizar la llamada con post

Comment: Gracias Leandro... Lo que pasa es que para postear que la webmethod función yo mismo la llamé en el page_load... Se supone que si la paso vía el Browser no funciona porque ya es a través como dices una herramienta... Lo que hice fue pasar manual a la función del webmethod un valor e hice un response.write para ver qué devolvía...

Comment: gracias a todos, ya pude leer el JSON, era un tema de formato...